# Pandas multiply two data frames to get product

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two data frames with different variable names

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,2,3],'B':[5,5,6]})
>>> df1
   A  B
0  2  5
1  2  5
2  3  6
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C':[3,3,3],'D':[5,5,6]})
>>> df2
   C  D
0  3  5
1  3  5
2  3  6
```

I want to create a third data frame where the n-th column is the product of the n-th columns in the first two data frames. In the above example, df3 would have two columns X and Y, where `df.X = df.A * df.C` and `df.Y = df.B * df.D`

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[6,6,9],'Y':[25,25,36]})
>>> df3
   X   Y
0  6  25
1  6  25
2  9  36
```

Is there a simple pandas function that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `mul`, to multiply `df1` by the values of `df2`:

```
df3 = df1.mul(df2.values)
df3.columns = ['X','Y']

>>> df3
   X   Y
0  6  25
1  6  25
2  9  36
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use numpy as:

```
df3 = np.multiply(df1, df2)
```

Note: Most numpy operations will take Pandas Series or DataFrame.